# How do I clone a specific Git branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

Git clone will clone remote branch into local.

Is there any way to clone a specific branch by myself without switching branches on the remote repository?

Answer (score 2475, accepted):

```
git clone --single-branch --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>
```

The `--single-branch` option is valid from version [1.7.10](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt) and later.

Please see also the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568323/134077) which many people prefer.

You may also want to make sure you understand the difference. And the difference is: by invoking `git clone --branch <branchname> url` you're fetching *all* the branches and checking out one. That may, for instance, mean that your repository has a 5kB documentation or wiki branch and 5GB data branch. And whenever you want to edit your frontpage, you may end up cloning 5GB of data.

Again, that is not to say `git clone --branch` is not the way to accomplish that, it's just that it's not *always* what you want to accomplish, when you're asking about cloning a specific branch.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191121/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-krelin-hacker-how-to-clone-a-specific-git-bran).

Comment: Pardon me, are you sure about the part you said "you're fetching all..."? I read somewhere that git fetch doesn't actually "copy" any files, it just fetches metadata and information about the changes. So it should be relatively light weight... Maybe you've used the word "fetch" literally and not from the git vocabulary?

Comment: @aderchox, no it will actually fetch all the content. It is pretty smart about things it transfers when you update, but when you clone a big repository it actually pulls the history, unless you explicitly tell it not to. But it will still fetch the tip of the branch. What `git fetch` does not — it does not check out files, but that's not about the transfer.

Comment: Often you will also want `--depth 1` so that you only get the latest.  This can save a lot of downloading time.

Comment: `git clone -b branch_name --single-branch 'repo_url'`

Comment: You can also `clone` with `--no-checkout` at all, and then `set` a filter with `sparse-checkout` with a particular `--branch` as well to just clone a sub-set of the files in the branch that match your filter, which can even be just a list of file paths that you want (you may want to use `--no-cone`). This set of features is currently evolving from `git` v2.24 to v2.34. You may need to check which features you've got in your version.

Answer (score 8924):

```
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

Example:

```
git clone -b my-branch git@github.com:user/myproject.git
```

With Git 1.7.10 and later, add `--single-branch` to prevent fetching of all branches. Example, with OpenCV 2.4 branch:

```
git clone -b opencv-2.4 --single-branch https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
```

Comment: pierr: I'm not sure if this answers the description of the problem given above, but it *does* answer the actual question - how to clone a specific branch of a repository.  I voted this up because it's the answer I was googling for when I came to this page.

Comment: This works. It points the new HEAD at the specified branch rather than at the HEAD-branch in myproject. However, it still fetches *all* branches. See @edmar-miyake's answer.

Comment: It answers the description of the problem if you add a --depth X to the command. If you do so, it will clone only the specified branch and its  last content.

Comment: thx for `--single-branch`; git 2.5 is out at time of writing this. Don't care for older versions.

Comment: I used the above command, which did pull from github - but I pulled it into master, because that's the branch I was on - it did not create the branch I was cloning locally. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: we can also use : 
`git checkout -b <Branch_Name>`
`git pull origin <Branch_Name>`
, it works with me xD

or, **simiply** 

`git fetch <Branch_Name>`
`git checkout <Branch_Name>`

Comment: @jorge Why `-b` option requires a separate `--single-branch` flag? Does `-b` alone clones all branches?

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ Hi, the `--single-branch` IS NOT required. As you can see in the manpages, git clone "...creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository" and "--[no-]single-branch  Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or the primary branch remote’s HEAD points at."

You save some time in big repos I guess.

Comment: Thanks, for helping. `--single-braches` aren't required to work remind that <3

Comment: This is especially helpful for scripting the installation of code that doesn't need to be built, for instance config files. I keep my NGINX configs in a repo and my userdata script clones and moves them into place with rsync. There is no need to `cd` into the repo if you cloned with HEAD pointing to the right branch.

Comment: @JorgeE.Cardona Was really helped me. I was taking the pull so it is taking from "master" branch which is not reflecting my latest changes of other updated sub-branch.

Comment: @Dipak I'm happy it helped. I am unsure what is your question, the first command should include any children as well, but it sets the HEAD to the designed branch. Unless you are using `--single-branches` in which case you get only the commits leading to that branch and no other branches. Use `git log --graph --oneline --all` to see the whole tree.

Comment: Is there a way to include branch in the ssh/https url? eg `git clone  git@github.com:user/myproject.git/my-branch`

Comment: *NOTE* that `--single-branch` will cause future `git fetch` calls to only fetch that branch. You may find yourself later wondering why your tools don't show all the remote branches that you KNOW exist! Even after you fetch.

Answer (score 356):

Here is a really simple way to do it :)

Clone the repository

```
git clone <repository_url>
```

List all branches

```
git branch -a
```

Checkout the branch that you want

```
git checkout <name_of_branch>
```

Comment: This switched the working directory to the correct branch, but I'm not able to push any changes I make, because I'm not "currently on a branch".

Comment: This was the solution for me, since I had already cloned 'master'. I didn't know I could simply 'checkout' a remote branch.

Comment: This is probably the correct way to do it; best-practices-wise

Comment: git checkout mybranchname then git fetch done

Comment: This way doesn't clone only the choosen branch. This answer seems better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7349740/3075243. For example if a repo has many branches that are big enough that we don't wanna clone each one.

Comment: Very crisp answer. 

One additional things you have to do is:

After  this step: "git checkout <name_of_branch>"

Do this:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <local_branch>

Thanks.

Comment: Won't this retain old files/folders from the original checkout that are no longer present in new branch?

Comment: For me it doesn't work.  After clone when I run "git branch -a" it shows me nothing. Just blank space.

Comment: Not a good solution. By using `git clone <repository_url>` you're getting ALL branches...! then switch to `<name_of_branch>`.

Comment: If somebody creates new branch on github, how to fetch it ?

Answer (score 267):

To clone a branch **without** fetching other branches:

```
mkdir $BRANCH
cd $BRANCH
git init
git remote add -t $BRANCH -f origin $REMOTE_REPO
git checkout $BRANCH
```

Comment: Good solution. On older git (I have 1.5.5.6), a git branch --track $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH may be needed before the checkout.

Comment: Works, and also fetches just those tags present on the branch, which is what I wanted. (I actually wanted to fetch _multiple_ branches, but only selected ones; for that, it sufficed to repeatedly `remote add` and `checkout` as here, then `git remote rm origin` to clean up.)

Comment: Perfect solution for shallowly incorporating a specific tag of a git repo in another project. Recommend omitting `-f`  from the git remote command, then using `git fetch --depth=1 $BRANCH $TAG`, then `git checkout FETCH_HEAD`. The init is innocuous, and changing tags will automatically update the checked out code.

Comment: Unlike Michael Krelin's (3-step) answer, this one actually worked for me (git 1.7.9.5)

Comment: after alot of fail, this code is works to me.. `git version 2.9.2`

Answer (score 144):

Use:

```
git checkout -b <branch-name> <origin/branch_name>
```

For example in my case:

```
 git branch -a
* master
  origin/HEAD
  origin/enum-account-number
  origin/master
  origin/rel_table_play
  origin/sugarfield_customer_number_show_c
```

So to create a new branch based on my enum-account-number branch, I do:

```
git checkout -b enum-account-number origin/enum-account-number
```

After you hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, the following happens:

```
Branch enum-account-number set up to track remote branch refs/remotes/origin/enum-account-number.
Switched to a new branch "enum-account-number"
```

Comment: Note that it may be useful to `git pull origin` first so that `git branch -a` can list all new (current) remote branches.

Comment: Good point.  Probably `git fetch` is better so that the auto merge doesn't happen, though.

Comment: this solution is helpful for creating a new local branch, switching to it and setting up to track the corresponding remote branch

Answer (score 40):

Create a branch on the local system with that name. e.g. say you want to get the branch named `branch-05142011`

```
git branch branch-05142011 origin/branch-05142011
```

It'll give you a message:

```
$ git checkout --track origin/branch-05142011
Branch branch-05142011 set up to track remote branch refs/remotes/origin/branch-05142011.
Switched to a new branch "branch-05142011"
```

Now just checkout the branch like below and you have the code

```
git checkout branch-05142011
```

Comment: This will do too :
git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[new-local-branch]

Comment: has it right. Miyake (below) shows how to do it when the remote is added.

Comment: That should say, "PlanetUnknown has it right."

Comment: @PlanetUnknown Thanks for `git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[new-local-branch]`, I love that!

Comment: git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[new-local-branch] for the win

Comment: I tried `git branch ue5-early-access origin/ue5-early-access` and it errors: "fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/ue5-early-access'.", any tip?

Answer (score 35):

```
git --branch <branchname> <url>
```

But Bash completion don't get this key: `--branch`