# importing a git working directory to a second git repository

Tags: git

```
git version 1.7.4.1
Ubuntu
```

Currently I am working on a project at my company. Our git repository is on our local LAN server.

I have a private repository on unfuddle.

So I have cloned my project on my work's company and created some branches that I am currently working on.

I have a branched called i.e. work_branch.

I am wondering if I can import that work_branch into my unfuddle respository. However, I don't want to do this if it will affect my current working copy of my git repostory at work.

So basically I just want to add to this unfuddle repository. So I can push my changes to it. As well as our LAN Server.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/git-clone-a-specific-branch

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make an existing git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your repository on your work computer you can just push your branch called `work_branch` to your unfuddle repository.  First you have to set up a "remote" that refers to your unfuddle repository, e.g.:

```
 git remote add unfuddle <URL-of-the-unfuddle-repository>
```

Thereafter you can push the branch to that respository with:

```
 git push unfuddle work_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for git submodules.

Check [this docs](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html)