# Change Git branch on SSH remote before cloning

Tags: git, ssh, branch, clone

I am trying to clone a repo from an SSH remote like this:

```
git clone "ssh://user@project.example.com/var/www/git/www"
```

This works OK but using this command I am actually cloning the "master" branch of the repo, but instead I want to clone another branch which is called "dev2".

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/git-clone-a-specific-branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after git clone.

you can just

`git branch --track dev2 origin/dev2`
`git checkout dev2`

to change your branch to dev2 easily.

or a short cut

```
git clone -b dev2 "ssh://user@project.example.com/var/www/git/www"
```

Comment: You will probably have to create a local branch first: `git branch --track dev2 origin/dev2`

Comment: Your answer now creates the branch but doesn't check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I want to clone a certain branch of a repo, I dont need to clone the entire repo, would that be possible?

Comment: `git clone -b <branch> "ssh://user@project.example.com/var/www/git/www"`

Comment: @KitHo: this will only checkout the branch after clone, it will still clone all branches

Comment: @knittl: the git will clone all the branches from the repository. It increases the flexibility of switching different branches without asking the remote repo again.

Comment: @KitHo: I know, I've been a git user for quite some time now :) the OP wanted to know in his comment how to clone a single branch only

Comment: @Kit Ho: Thank you very much. Your answer in the comments works for me so would be great if you can please update your main reply so I can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

with git you generally clone complete repositories (all branches). if you want to clone only a single branch and never get any other branches use the following commands:

```
git init project
cd project
git remote add -f -t dev2 origin 'ssh://user@project.example.com/var/www/git/www'
git checkout -b dev2 origin/dev2
```