# Cloning the same repository multiple times with Github for Windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Is it possible to clone the same repository multiple times with Github for Windows? The reason I ask is I want to clone the Laravel framework multiple times, once for each project I'm using it for.

Comment: I figured out this is pretty easy to do with Git for Windows since you can clone into any directory, but still would like to know if its possible with Github for Windows

Comment: I hate to be _that guy_, but why use Github for Windows in the first place? There are other alternatives that simplify Git without being as restrictive, like [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).

Comment: If you couldn't do that, I'd suggest you to contact GitHub. They tend to reply quickly, and maybe you can get this bug solved/feature implemented in a near future.

Comment: You should get used to the thought that GitHub for Windows is only made for the very few most common usecases. The one you're asking for is simply a usecase for "plain vanilla Git" and is dead easy to do with it.

Comment: Also see this question for an alternative workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000336/cloning-multiple-branches-in-github-for-windows

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible, and it is simple enough

In git bash:

```
git clone <repo> <directory>
git clone <repo> <directory_2>
.............................
git clone <repo> <directory_N-1>
git clone <repo> <directory_N>
```

Repo is your repository URL, and all those directory[N] are your desired directory names

Also, why not just make a copy of an already cloned repo to another directory?

Comment: making a copy does not show it in the list , local or github since it has same git info I guess

Comment: it really doesn't matter, each cloned copy of a repo is the same as any other (assuming there were no new commits between clone operations). To show an repository in your repo list on github you need to fork it, not just clone.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from @baldrs (cloning multiple times) works, but is not the way it is thought to be.

Git has a feature called `worktree`, that's what should be used here:

```
git clone --bare <repo> ./repo.git
cd ./repo.git
git worktree add ../<directory> master
git worktree add ../<directory_2> master
......
git worktree add ../<directory_N> master
```

This is the better way to go, especially when it is a large repository, as the git object database only gets cloned **once** and every worktree uses the same database.

Using this approach, it is no problem to switch branches individually if need be, don't worry.

See git documentation for details: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Comment: Well, git `worktree` did not exist in 2012, so a modern update to that question is surely welcome