# trouble cloning from branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I am using github and I have a few branches made from a backup branch and I am trying to git clone from the sub branch lets call it "x".  I have made a lot of changes and pushed them to the "x" branch but now when I git clone, it pulls that branch + the backup branch.  Is there a way to only clone from the "x" branch without git cloning its parent branch?  On git the "x" branch looks exactly how I want it and some things are deleted that are in the backup branch however git clone sends those deleted files as well.  I am a little confused and I hope this is a simple git clone "url" addition.  Thank you anyone who knows what I need to do to only clone the "x" branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/clone-a-specific-git-branch.

Comment: Copy the url on HTTPS clone URL
and run: git clone https://github.com/Sample/repoename.git

Comment: so that usually works but to desclose the parent branch you have to run:

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to run.

```
git clone -b branchName --single-branch https://github.com/clone.url
```

Hope this helps someone