# How clone a specific branch in bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, ruby-on-rails-4, github, bitbucket-api

I have a remote repository hosted in bitbucket, but when I want clone this repository to my pc
Bitbucket clones the master branch
I want clone another branch called static_pages_exercises hosted too in the same remote project. Is that possible.

```
Error:it clones the remote master branch no the remote static-pages-exercises branch


daniel:~/workspace$ mkdir sample_app
daniel:~/workspace$ git init .
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/fernando/workspace/.git/
fernando@fernando:~/workspace$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:ferbad1212/sample_app.git
Cloning into 'sample_app'...
remote: Counting objects: 139, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (124/124), done.
remote: Total 139 (delta 42), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (139/139), 23.05 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (42/42), done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone a specific Git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/clone-a-specific-git-branch)

Comment: add `-b static-pages-exercises`

Comment: Thanks friend .Is there any way to clone all remote branches?.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below command

git clone --branch branchname cloneUrl

example

git clone --branch feature https://cloneurl