# Ignore text=auto in .gitattributes file

Tags: git, gitattributes

I checked out a branch `foo`, and now I want to switch to branch `bar`.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
<300 files follow>
```

Someone has a `.gitattributes` file on `foo` that includes

```
text=auto
```

All of the "changes" are newline changes.

I could remove the file, switch branches, and then add it back.

```
rm .gitattributes
git checkout bar
git checkout .gitattributes
```

Is this the best (fastest/least typing) way?

EDIT: To be clear, I just want to switch branches. I'm only reading the repo. I don't want to change anything other than the working tree. But I can't.

Comment: Stash and then apply the changes with -Xignore-eol or whatever it is?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to switch branches. I'm only reading the repo.

Then removing the `.gitattributes` is indeed one possible solution, provided you don't try to checkout again foo once on bar (or that .gitattributes would appear again)

Another option would be to simply [clone the repo directly at the `bar` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568323/6309), creating a separate working tree.

Comment: @PaulDraper Ok, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.