# IntelliJ IDEA git clone a specific branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, branch, clone

I need to create a new project based on a specific git branch.
I selected:
`File->new->Project from Version Control->Git`
however there are only 3 fields which result in cloning the master branch:

- Git Repository URL
- Parent Directory
- Directory Name

However there is no option to submit the specific branch.

Is there anyway to clone a specific branch using Git in IntelliJ?

Comment: Once you've cloned the repo, just switch branches using the drop-down in the bottom right corner of the window.

Comment: You don't clone Git branches; you clone a repository, then check out the branch you need.

Answer (score 14):

You misunderstood Git. In Git as in any DVCS by default you clone the full repository including all branches. Only for the default branch of the cloned repository (most often this is `master`), there is a local branch created autmatically and checked out. But you still have all branches of the cloned repository present as remote tracking branches in your local repository. So just checkout the branch you want after you did the clone. If you clone with the commandline instead, you can give the clone command the branch that should be checked out after the clone automatically if different from the default branch, but IJ does not have an option for that apparently. But switching the branch after the cloning is easy.

Answer (score 12):

As Vampire say, you have to clone all the git project, then change branch.
You can change the branch pressing on bottom-right > Git:master > Remote Branches > chose your branch > Checkout as new local branch

Comment: BOTTOM RIGHT !  It was hiding (in plain site).  I think I know why the question was posed.  You don't get the "import as maven" or "import as gradle" voodoo when you change the branch at a later time.

Answer (score 6):

First you do checkout from master, once done go right side bottom corner, and Click on Git, popup will open , click on show more,it will populate all branches in remote Branches. ( better drag and maximize that box) . and select your required branch from Remote Branches and do check out. Automatically your selected branch will come as your project in intellij. [Image of Inttelij Bottom Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRCkQ.png)

[Select Show more Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udYSK.png)

[Do Check your required branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKoW8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can clone single branch by command line which explained here: [How do I clone a specific Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911126/2877427) But this is not the straight road to do that.

Lets explain straight road to do that with `IntelliJ IDEA`:

1. Clone project (every repository has one link to clone regardless  number of branches).
2. Go to `Git` => `Branches`

[image]

3. Choose specific-branch which you need then click on `Checkout`

[image]

That is it :)