# How to sync my local repo properly with my git project ?

Tags: git, github, branch, clone

I have seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-to-clone-a-specific-git-branch) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git) but they don't quite fit my problem.

I have a remote repo with 3 branches (master, branch1, branch2) with many commits on each and I have also a local repo with some files and more recent work.

*I tried to -git init and add my remote to pull from branch1, clean the code then push. That was the idea to have a clean git project and a clean local repo. But it didn't worked. I had only my branch master and no possibility to switch to my branch "branch1".

*I tried also to -git clone my branch1 only. It worked. I got all the files with the last version from my branch1. But i had no .git and my branch1 was considered as my branch master.

*I tried to clone my entire project. But still, my branches do not appear with -git branch.

So I might need a little help to understand the proper way to do it. How do I sync my local repo (with more recent work) properly with my branch1 without losing or erasing my work ?

I also would like avoid conflits or cleaning a mess in the process.

Thank you all in advance for your help !

Comment: After adding the remote as you say on the first recipe, did you fetch from it?

Comment: I never used the -git fetch command before. It looks like it is the correct solution for my problem. I will try it at work tomorrow and tell you how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my current problem following [this page](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch) but the downside was I had to use -git clone .

What I did not understand before was my remote branches could be found with `-git branch -r` but I had to create a local branch to match the corrections I wanted to add to one of the remote branches.

So finally, what I did was :

```
-git clone <my_remote_repo>
-git fetch <my_remote_repo> <branch1>
-git checkout <branch1>
-git status
```

=> I erased the old files on my local repo , copied the new version in the same local repo , and then i used the usual

```
-git add <files>
-git commit -"m" <comment>
-git push <my_remote_repo> <branch1>
```

That might not have been the cleanest way, but it worked. If anyone have a more efficient way to do that, please don't hesitate to share.