# Does `git clone` copy every branch on the remote repository?

Tags: git

Does `git clone` copy every branch on the remote repository?

Is it possible to request it to clone some branches but not some other branches, just like `git fetch` does via its refspec argument?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-to-clone-a-specific-git-branch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a single branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `git clone`, like all the rest of Git, doesn't really concern itself all that much with *branch names*, but rather with *commits*.  It's just that Git (and `git clone`) needs names in order to *find* commits.

The `git clone` command itself essentially consists of:

- making a new directory (or using an existing but empty directory)
- running `git init` in that directory
- configuring items here as necessary and appropriate, including doing a `git remote add` to save the URL
- running `git fetch` using the remote just added
- running `git checkout`

Hence, the question really boils down to: *Can you control the `fetch =` setting for the remote that `git clone` adds?*

The answer is *Yes, but only to a limited extent.*  The limits are:

- `--mirror` sets the refspec to `+refs/*:refs/*`.
- `--bare` sets the refspec to `+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` and `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.
- `--single-branch` or any of the commands that imply it set the refspec as appropriate for that operation.

In the absence of either of these, you get a standard refspec.  Hence, `--single-branch` lets you pick *one* branch to clone (by changing to a single-branch refspec), and `--mirror` lets you go outside the `refs/heads/` namespace, but there is, at least as of today, no argument(s) that will do some intermediate subset.  You can, instead, do your own `mkdir` / `git init` / `git remote add` / `git config` / `git fetch` / `git checkout` sequence of commands, if you wish to achieve some special result.