# Git clone old version of repository?

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to git clone an older version of the OpenQuake engine than the master version (https://github.com/gem/oq-engine). The version I am interested in is the last used for Python 2.7 (the 2.9 commit - https://github.com/gem/oq-engine/tree/engine-2.9). The only answers I can find are for repositories in which you are the owner of said repository.

Any help much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just checkout the branch you're interested in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a specific Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-to-clone-a-specific-git-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clone%5D+branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
git clone https://github.com/gem/oq-engine.git
git checkout engine-2.9
```