# How to get a specific branch by url? Git

Tags: git

In my server, I've written a bash script that gets last changes from my Github repo.
I pull the latest `master` branch with url as following:
`git pull myuser:mypassword@github.com/myrepo.git`
Now I want to get a specific branch in this bash script? Not `clone`, I want to `pull` a specific branch. Is it possible to do that with URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a specific Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-do-i-clone-a-specific-git-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual page for `git pull`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) summarises the command format as:

```
git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]
```

- `<options>` are all the optional arguments beginning with `-`
- `<repository>` is specified either as a URL or a pre-configured "remote"
- `<refspec>` is most commonly the name of a branch

So in your example, you have a repository argument of `myuser:mypassword@github.com/myrepo.git`, and can add a branch name as the `<refspec>` to give quite simply:

```
git pull myuser:mypassword@github.com/myrepo.git some-branch-name
```

More commonly, you would set up a "remote", which is just an alias for that repository URL:

```
# set up once
git remote add some-memorable-name myuser:mypassword@github.com/myrepo.git
# use from then on
git pull some-memorable-name some-branch-name
```

That's why you'll see plenty of examples online of commands like `git pull upstream master` - `upstream` refers to some particular remote repository, and `master` is the branch to fetch and merge.