# How to clone development branch when we git clone a repository

Tags: git, repository, git-clone

How to clone development branch when we git clone a repository, right now when we clone it checkouts the master branch by default

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a specific Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-do-i-clone-a-specific-git-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clone%5D+specific+branch